# ms azure: connecting bot with luis app

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I want to create a bot using luis, fill it with entities and intents and use C# to handle the responses.

I have created an app on eu.luis.ai, but I couldn't find out, how i can edit the code of this app.

I have created a web app bot with luis template on the azure portal and can edit the code but i couldn't find out how i can create intents, entities and so on.

Do i have to connect them somehow?

Or how do i create a bot, so that i can fill it with content and edit the code?

Comment: I tried to make your question a bit more readable, but I still think it is a bit too broad/unspecific.

Answer (score 0):

LUIS and Bot Framework Bots are separate, meaning you don't need to use LUIS with your bot and vice versa. As such, you as the developer need to manually connect the two of them together. For the entities and intents aspect, you will need to create them in the LUIS portal. Then correspondingly, you can modify your bots code to handle the new intents and entities from your LUIS app.

You didn't specify, but I am going out on a limb and assuming that your Web App Bot is in a European datacenter. To minimize latency between LUIS and your bot, make sure to set your domain. Example below:

```
[LuisModel("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", domain: "westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com", staging: true)]
[Serializable]
public class YourLUISDialog : LuisDialog
{
```

- [LUIS C# Tutorial Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample#connect-your-luis-app-to-the-bot)
- [List of all valid LUIS Endpoints](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5819c76f40a6350ce09de1ac/operations/5819c77140a63516d81aee78)
- [The code excerpt is from this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2998#issuecomment-310166028)